# Software similar to iTerm2 but for Windows powershell?

Tags: powershell, terminal-emulator

Is there a similar software as [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/features.html) (which is only for Mac) that can be installed on Windows 8 and used instead of the powershell?

The software should have similar features to those of iTerm2.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Check out the answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/268042/terminal-emulator-with-split-panes-for-windows-7-64-bit).

---

Not a perfect answer, but if you haven't tried it, take a look at [Powershell ISE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise-guide) -- which is probably already installed on your system.

As you might get from the name, it's an "Integrated Script Environment", probably more IDE than iTerm. Yet it has many features similar to iTerm2 that make it better in some ways than running in plain Powershell windows -- tabs, color preferences, etc. Below, I've got a screengrab with two tabs & the Options pane open.

[image: screengrab of Powershell ISE with options pane open]

In any event, if you haven't tried it, it'll get you a little closer.